# Making a game in C, not C++. Need assistance with saving, replacing and sorting scores in a txt file

Tags: c, string, sorting, file-io

I'm trying to code a function in C! Not C++. I couldn't figure out how to actually go about it so this is just an outline of what I would like to do. The purpose of this function is to save the top 10 high scores to a txt file. It needs to have the winners name and amount of wins next to their name. Each time a round is finished, the winner will get their name printed into the file with the total amount of times they've won. If a returning user wins, their name should only appear once. Below is an example of how the txt file should look when displayed and what I'm trying to go for code-wise.

EX.

```
1  Joe 10
2  Jen 8
3  Bob 7
4  Caleb 6
5  Lance 5
6  Siobhan 3
7  Laurel 2
8  Jack 2
9  Gabriel 1
10 Timmy 1
```

[Outline of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9MCS.png)

Comment: You shouldn't really write into a text file, but read the whole thing, make any changes, and make a new file (or overwrite entire previous file). Suppose you try to overwrite `10` with `7`, and `7` with `10`? Can you see it will screw up the line endings?

Comment: You need to make an attempt, show your code and ask a more specific question. Without that we can only give general suggestions. In general it is difficult to replace just part of a text file. Probably should start with reading the whole file into memory, adjusting the scores and then over-writing the original file with new contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure to represent each entry. The simplest that comes to mind is something like this

```
struct record_entry{
    char name[BUFLEN];
    int score;
};
```

Then you need another data structure to store these `entry_record` objects. Ideally, something like a C++ map or Java HasMap (i.e. a hash table) to store all the entries by using the `name` field as your keys. This, however, requires you to implement your own hash table and if you do not want to do it, you can use C arrays.

Use standard library's [`qsort` function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=qsort&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) to sort the entries in the array. A simple `compar` function for `struct entry_record` could be

```
int cmp_score(const void* e1, const void* e2){
    int s1, s2;
    s1 = ((struct record_entry*)e1)->score;
    s2 = ((struct record_entry*)e2)->score;
    if (s1 < s2)
        return -1;
    else if (s1 == s2)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Then, you need a function to update your data structure (hash table or array) based on the new entry. You should implement something similar to [`insert_or_assign()` method of std::map (C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) or [`put()` method of Java's HashMap class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-). Below is a simple function that achieves this

```
size_t update_records(struct record_entry **ep, size_t n, struct record_entry ne){
    size_t i;
    int exist=0;
    size_t nsize = n;
    struct record_entry *tmp = *ep;

    /* check if the entry is already there */
    for (i=0; i<nsize; i++){
        if (strcmp(tmp[i].name, ne.name) == 0){
            exist = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (exist){
    /* update the record */
        tmp[i].score = ne.score;
    } else {
    /* add a new entry */
        nsize++;
        tmp = realloc(*ep, nsize * sizeof(struct record_entry));
        strncpy(tmp[nsize-1].name, ne.name, BUFLEN);
        tmp[nsize-1].score=ne.score;
    }

    /* sort the array */
    qsort(tmp, nsize, sizeof(struct record_entry), cmp_score);

    *ep = tmp;

    return nsize;
}
```

`update_records` returns the size of the new array; `n+1` if the entry you pass as an argument is not in the array (i.e. a new record), or `n` if it already there. It updates the existing record in the latter case of course.

The code snippet below does something similar to what you want to achieve, simply get the data from your text file and add error handling where appropriate. The logic is the same though

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFLEN     32
#define N    4

struct record_entry{
    char name[BUFLEN];
    int score;
};

int cmp_score(const void* e1, const void* e2){
    int s1, s2;
    s1 = ((struct record_entry*)e1)->score;
    s2 = ((struct record_entry*)e2)->score;
    if (s1 < s2)
        return -1;
    else if (s1 == s2)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

size_t update_records(struct record_entry **ep, size_t n, struct record_entry ne){
    size_t i;
    int exist=0;
    size_t nsize = n;
    struct record_entry *tmp = *ep;

    /* check if the entry is already there */
    for (i=0; i<nsize; i++){
        if (strcmp(tmp[i].name, ne.name) == 0){
            exist = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (exist){
    /* update the record */
        tmp[i].score = ne.score;
    } else {
    /* add a new entry */
        nsize++;
        tmp = realloc(*ep, nsize * sizeof(struct record_entry));
        strncpy(tmp[nsize-1].name, ne.name, BUFLEN);
        tmp[nsize-1].score=ne.score;
    }

    /* sort the array */
    qsort(tmp, nsize, sizeof(struct record_entry), cmp_score);

    *ep = tmp;

    return nsize;
}

int main(){
    struct record_entry *entries, *p, new_entry;
    int i;
    size_t ns;

    entries = malloc(N * sizeof(struct record_entry));

    strncpy(entries[0].name, "Test0", BUFLEN);
    entries[0].score=0;
    strncpy(entries[1].name, "Test1", BUFLEN);
    entries[1].score=1;
    strncpy(entries[2].name, "Test2", BUFLEN);
    entries[2].score=2;
    strncpy(entries[3].name, "Test3", BUFLEN);
    entries[3].score=3;

    /* sort the array */
    qsort(entries, N, sizeof(struct record_entry), cmp_score);

    printf("before\n");
    printf("===============\n");
    for (i=N-1; i>=0; i--){
        printf("%d %s\t%d\n",i ,entries[i].name, entries[i].score);
    }

    printf("\nname : ");
    scanf("%s", new_entry.name);
    printf("score : ");
    scanf("%d",&new_entry.score);
    getc(stdin);

    ns = update_records(&entries, N, new_entry);

    printf("\nafter return\n");
    printf("===============\n");
    for (i=ns-1; i>=0; i--){
        printf("%d %s\t%d\n",i ,entries[i].name, entries[i].score);
    }

    free(entries);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code with a new entry

```
before
===============
3 Test3    3
2 Test2    2
1 Test1    1
0 Test0    0

name : test
score : 7

after return
===============
4 test    7
3 Test3    3
2 Test2    2
1 Test1    1
0 Test0    0
```

and when I update an existing entry

```
before
===============
3 Test3    3
2 Test2    2
1 Test1    1
0 Test0    0

name : Test2
score : 9

after return
===============
3 Test2    9
2 Test3    3
1 Test1    1
0 Test0    0
```